# not knowing how to change the indicator color in Sfcalender

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api, sfcalendar

Am using Sfcalender as a calender for my app, and am having trouble changing the blue color of the blue meeting indicator The UI where you could see the blue indicator that I want to change it color
[image]

Comment: could you provide code snippet that you are using it will helpful to debug more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method `getColor()` in your event class which extends `CalendarDataSource`. Also you can put different colors to your events.

```
class EventDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  EventDataSource(List<Event> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
  }
  Event getAppointments(int index) => appointments![index] as Event;
    
@override
Color getColor(int index) => *color*;
```

In this class you also can override every method from absctract CalendarDataSource class. Check documentation of this class to look for all methods.